# Get loop index of outer loop

Tags: jinja2, template-engine

In jinja, the variable loop.index holds the iteration number of the current running loop.

When I have nested loops, how can I get in the inner loop the current iteration of an outer loop?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Store it in a variable, for example:

```
{% for i in a %}
    {% set outer_loop = loop %}
    {% for j in a %}
        {{ outer_loop.index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just note that the index will start from 1 and not 0.

Comment: Also note loop.index0 would let you access index starting from 0 (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for)

Comment: what if we wanted to show the loop index as row number in a table? this code here isn't considering that and inner loop will be shown as 1 untill it ends. how we handle that?

Answer (score -13):

You can use loop.parent inside a nested loop to get the context of the outer loop

```
{% for i in a %}
    {% for j in i %}
        {{loop.parent.index}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is a much cleaner solution than using temporary variables.
Source - http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for

Comment: This is wrong. Jinja doesn't support .parent. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop and http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for.

Comment: Perhaps @KannanGanesan was thinking of [twig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734849/328817).