# How to output loop.counter in python jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2, templating-engine

I want to be able to output the current loop iteration to my template.

According to [the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/), there is a `loop.counter` variable that I am trying to use:

```
<ul>
{% for user in userlist %}
  <li>
      {{ user }} {{loop.counter}}
  </li>
      {% if loop.counter == 1 %}
          This is the First user
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But is being outputed to my template. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 578, accepted):

The counter variable inside the loop is called `loop.index` in Jinja2.

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template

>>> s = "{% for element in elements %}{{loop.index}} {% endfor %}"
>>> Template(s).render(elements=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
1 2 3 4
```

In addition to `loop.index`, there is also

- `loop.index0` (index starting at `0`)
- `loop.revindex` (reverse index; ending at `1`)
- `loop.revindex0` (reverse index; ending at `0`)
- Even more at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/.

Comment: What if there is nested-for loop? How will it work there?
How to access outer for loop's index when inside of the nested for?

Comment: It is possible to store the outer loop index in a variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567300/2666094

Answer (score 125):

Inside of a `for`-loop block, you can access some special variables, such as `loop.index` (but not `loop.counter`). From [the official docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for):

| Variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `loop.index` | The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed) |
| `loop.index0` | The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed) |
| `loop.revindex` | The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1 indexed) |
| `loop.revindex0` | The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0 indexed) |
| `loop.first` | True if first iteration. |
| `loop.last` | True if last iteration. |
| `loop.length` | The number of items in the sequence. |
| `loop.cycle` | A helper function to cycle between a list of sequences. |
| `loop.depth` | Indicates how deep in a recursive loop the rendering currently is. Starts at level 1 |
| `loop.depth0` | Indicates how deep in a recursive loop the rendering currently is. Starts at level 0 |
| `loop.previtem` | The item from the previous iteration of the loop. Undefined during the first iteration. |
| `loop.nextitem` | The item from the following iteration of the loop. Undefined during the last iteration. |
| `loop.changed(*val)` | True if previously called with a different value (or not called at all). |

Answer (score 35):

If you are using Django, use `forloop.counter` instead of `loop.counter`:

```
<ul>
{% for user in userlist %}
  <li>
      {{ user }} {{forloop.counter}}
  </li>
      {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
          This is the First user
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I am getting `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'forloop' is undefined`

Comment: use `loop` with jinja; here is [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures). `forloop` is for django templates.

Comment: The question is clearly asking about jinja, why are we giving answers about Django templates here...

Answer (score 0):

Real-life example:

```
{% for image in item['images'] %}
    {% set image_id = item_id ~ '-preview-' ~ loop.index0 %}
    <div id="{{ image_id }}" class="overlay">
        <a class="cancel" href="#{{ item_id }}"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            {% set src = image if image.startswith('http') else '/static/images/store/' ~ item_id ~ '/' ~ image %}
            <a href="{{ src }}"><img class="modal-img" src="{{ src }}"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```