# Number Rows in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I was wondering if there was an easy way to implement numbers into my HTML/Javascript table.

Here is the current code:

```
<table style="width:75%", border="2">

    <th>Club</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>Played Games</th>

    {% for team, score, game in data %}
    <tr>
    <td><strong>{{team}}</strong> </td>
    <td><emph> {{score}}</emph> <br/></td>
    <td>{{game}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

</table>
```

I will not post my python/flask code because I don't believe it is necessary.

All I would like to do is add a position column from 1 to the end.

Please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job for you.

I have added a position column to your table. For data in the table I am putting loop counter `loop.index` there. You can add +1 to loop counter If you want the counter to start from 1 instead of 0.

```
<table style="width:75%", border="2">
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Club</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>Played Games</th>

    {% for team, score, game in data %}
    <tr><strong>{{loop.index}}</strong> </td>
    <td><strong>{{team}}</strong> </td>
    <td><strong>{{team}}</strong> </td>
    <td><emph> {{score}}</emph> <br/></td>
    <td>{{game}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

</table>
```

Source: [How to output loop.counter in python jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145434/how-to-output-loop-counter-in-python-jinja-template)

Comment: Awesome! This is the answer. What, essentially, does "loop.index" do?

Comment: It gets the current loops index. So If a for loop is going on it will maintain an internal counter and get the value for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this natively with CSS using `counter` if you don't wish to modify the code for your loop. Here's a live example:

```css
table {
  counter-reset: position;
  width: 75%;
}

table td:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: position;
  content: counter(position);
}
```

```html
<table border="2">

  <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Club</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>Played Games</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Team</strong></td>
    <td><emph>Score</emph><br/></td>
    <td>Game</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Team</strong></td>
    <td><emph>Score</emph><br/></td>
    <td>Game</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Team</strong></td>
    <td><emph>Score</emph><br/></td>
    <td>Game</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```