# Loop issue in jinja2 template

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to build a configuration file dynamically with Ansible, using a Jinja2 template.

In Ansible, I've defined a role in which I have the template and the set of variables.

I want my output file to look like this :

```
  models:
    model1:
      username: user1
      password: password1
    model2:
      username: user2
      password: password2
```

I have defined my variables like so :

```
model_list:
  name:
    - model1
    - model2
  user:
    - user1
    - user2
  pass:
    - password1
    - password2
```

My .j2 template :

```
{% for model in vars[model_list] %}
  {{ model.name }}
    username: {{ model.user }}
    password: {{ model.pass }}
{% endfor %}
```

My playbook is quite simple :

```
- name: Building config file
template:
  src: ./config.j2
  dest: my/path/config
```

When I run the playbook I've got the following error :

```
fatal: [FRADEV048]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": 
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: dict object has no element {u'user': 
u'user1', u'name': u'model1', u'pass': u'password1'}"}
```

I'm quite new in programming so I don't really see where my error is ... Any clues ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template content

```
models:
{% for model in model_list.name %}
    {{ model }}:
        username: {{ model_list.user[loop.index0] }}
        password: {{ model_list.pass[loop.index0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959173/5439195