# Numbered loop in Jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to make a quiz app using Django, Jinja2 and PostgreSQL. I want to number the questions but I don't know how to because python doesn't use a counter in for loops (e.g. for exercise in exercises - no for loop here)

I've tried to change the for loop

```
(for exercise in exercises)
```

so it has a counter

```
(for x in myrange)
```

and defining myrange in views.py to be a range(1, len(exercitii+1))
but after that I didn't know how to access the elements inside the Jinja template.
I tried to access the exercises with

```
{exercitii.x-1.intrebare}}
```

but it didn't work.

html template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    </div>
    <div id="middle-section" class="container-fluid container-fluid-margin">
            <div class="content-quiz">
                <form action="{% url 'exercitiu' lectii.id %}" method="POST" id="quiz">
                        {% for exercitiu in exercitii %}
                        <div class="row content-block"> 
                                <div class="col-lg-10 text-card">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="card card-custom">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{exercitiu.id}} - {{exercitiu.intrebare}}</h5>
                                                    <div class="card-text">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers" id="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-A" value="A" />
                                                            <label for="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-A">A) {{exercitiu.variante.0}} </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="card-text">
                                                                <input type="radio" name="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers" id="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-B" value="B" />
                                                                <label for="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-B">B) {{exercitiu.variante.1}} </label>
                                                    </div> 
                                                    <div class="card-text">
                                                                <input type="radio" name="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers" id="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-C" value="C" />
                                                                <label for="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-C">C) {{exercitiu.variante.2}} </label>
                                                    </div> 
                                                    <div class="card-text">
                                                                <input type="radio" name="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers" id="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-D" value="D" />
                                                                <label for="question-{{exercitiu.id}}-answers-D">D) {{exercitiu.variante.3}} </label>
                                                    </div>   
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <input type="submit" value="Trimite" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-login-custom" style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
        </div> 
    </div>               
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Exercises
from .models import Lectie

def exercitii(req):
    lectii = Lectie.objects.all().order_by("id")
    context = {
        'lectii': lectii
    }
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/exercitii-selector.html', context)

def exercitiu(req, lectie_id):
    lectii = get_object_or_404(Lectie, pk=lectie_id)
    exercitiiObj = Exercises.objects.filter(idLectie=lectie_id)
    context = {
        'lectii': lectii,
        'exercitii': exercitiiObj
    }
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/exercitii.html', context)
```

(lectie = lesson, lectii = lessons, exercitii = exercises)

So how can I number the questions from exercitiiObj in the template? Right now the output is the exercise ID from the DB which isn't helpful at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out [`enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean).

Comment: @EndreBoth I've already did. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in jinja. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output loop.counter in python jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145434/how-to-output-loop-counter-in-python-jinja-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to get the iteration number of the for loop in `jinja`.

`Jinja` provides a very convenient loop variable, it has a property called `loop.counter` which is *1-indexed*, and `loop.counter0` which is *0-indexed*. [View Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for)

And if you're using DjangoTemplate, then those become `forloop.counter0` and `forloop.counter`. [View Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)