# I need index in for loop and use of modulo with that index in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I taken for in which I can't use loop index due to some reasons.I want to use something like {{set i=0}} and using modulo{%} with that I variable.in jinja template.

I used

```
{{Set i=1}}
{% for item in items %}
{% if I % 2==0%}
Print("hello")
{% endif%}
{% set i=i+1 %}
{% endfor%}
```

It's not working

Comment: `{{loop.index}}` would return the index. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147197/2681662, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537466/2681662

Comment: @MSH "I can't use loop index due to some reasons", the OP says, as weird as those unknown reasons may be.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`namespace`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#assignments) variable to allow access to the variable from an inner scope created by a `for` loop:

```
{{ set ns = namespace(i=1)}}
{% for item in items %}
{% if ns.i % 2 == 0%}
Print("hello")
{% endif %}
{% set ns.i = ns.i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```