# access loop.index when within another loop in twig

Tags: twig

How can i access the loop's index when i'm in a second loop? like this:

```
      {% for i in range(0, 3) %}
          {% for j in range(0, 9) %}
           {{ loop1.index + loop2.index }}  // ?
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the application of this summation?

Comment: @Trix maybe to process linearly a two-dimensional stuff (like image processing): j being the column index while i being the row index

Answer (score 129, accepted):

In fact there's no need to set an extra variable. For two nested loops twig provides the so called `parent.loop` context.

To access the parents `loop.index` do this:

```
{% for i in range(0, 3) %}
    {% for j in range(0, 9) %}
        {{ loop.parent.loop.index + loop.index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also refer to the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html)

Comment: You can continue stacking `loop.parent` if needed. Here's an example of three levels: https://twigfiddle.com/b8skwh

Answer (score 4):

set a variable which hold the first `loop.index`

```
{% for i in range(0, 3) %}
    {% set loop1 = loop.index %}
    {% for j in range(0, 9) %}
        {{ loop1 + loop.index }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```