# how can I use 2 loop index on twig

Tags: twig

How can I  use loop.index in this code.

```
{% for veri in data %}

<li>no: {{loop.index}}</li> 
  {% for inveri in datain %}
<li>no: {{loop.index}}</li> 
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

[image]
.....

Comment: You already using it, aren't you?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this code is not true :
No:1
No:2
No:3
No:2...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access loop.index when within another loop in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730875/access-loop-index-when-within-another-loop-in-twig)

Comment: it is just second for loop. I want to do in first and second loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
{% set data  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] %}
{% set data2 = [1, 2, 3] %}

{% set i = 1 %}
{% for d in data %}
    {{ i }}
    {% set i = i + 1 %}

    {% for d2 in data2 %}
        {{ i }}
        {% set i = i + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/vt0nzh)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Goto u need to use `loop.parent.loop` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730875/access-loop-index-when-within-another-loop-in-twig)

---

```
{% set data = [1,2,3,4,5,] %}

{% for d in data %}
{{ loop.index0 * (data|length + 1) + 1 }}
    {% for d in data %}
{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 * (data|length + 1) + 1 + loop.index }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/z0sbjf)

---

```
{% set data = [1,2,3,4,5,] %}
{% set data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] %}

{% for d in data %}
{{ loop.index0 * (data2|length + 1) + 1 }}
    {% for d in data2 %}
{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 * (data2|length + 1) + 1 + loop.index }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

[twigfiddle with 2 data-sets](https://twigfiddle.com/8g8mkb)

Comment: I do not have a data. I have 2 data and 2 loops. it have not been worked.

Comment: This is just an example code. This works with 2 arrays as well, see updated answer in which I work with `data` and `data2`. This is StackOverflow, don't expect us to do all your work. Anticipate on the provided answer and try to use them in your own code. Don't expect answers you just can copy/paste and be done with it

Comment: Of course I tried and changed your code. just I said . But it have not been worked...

Comment: Works perfectly with 2 arrays in my 2nd example

Comment: Update your question to reflect your adjusted code then

Comment: Well this is my output, 1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10

11
    12
    13
     ...