# Python Jinjna variable doesnt keep value outside loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I am currently trying to fix an issue by using jinja variables, but somehow the variable does not keep the value outside the loop, even though I declared it before the loop begins:

```
{% set disablecounter = 0 %}

{% if disablecounter == 0 %}
    {% for einzelroom in all_einzelzimmer %}
        {% if zimmer.id == einzelroom.zimmer_id %}
            {% set price = einzelroom.preis %}
            <div class="preis-element">
                <p class="preis"> <span class="smallab"> ab </span> {{ price|int }}&euro; </p>
            </div>
            {% set disablecounter = disablecounter + 1 %}
            {{ disablecounter }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{{ disablecounter }}
```

The variable is `disablecounter` inside the loop it is `1` but outside it is still `0`

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Surrounding with a `with statement` also didnt worked:

```
{% with foo = 42 %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endwith %}

{% with %}
    {% set foo = 42 %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755046/jinja2-nested-loop-counter) by @Chris Warth.

Original answer by  @Peter Hollingsworth:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700975/5291566

```
{% with disablecounter = [0] %}

{% if disablecounter == [0] %}
    {% for einzelroom in all_einzelzimmer %}
        {% if zimmer.id == einzelroom.zimmer_id %}
            <div class="preis-element">
                <p class="preis"> <span class="smallab"> ab </span> {{ einzelroom.preis|int }}&euro; </p>
            </div>
            {% if disablecounter.append(disablecounter.pop() + 1) %}{% endif %} 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```