# In a nested for-loop, how can I access the outer loop index in a jinja template?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

`{{loop.index}}` correctly dereferences the innermost loop.  I'm not seeing a way to identify which loop index I'd like, however, if I have more than one loop nested.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get loop index of outer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567291/get-loop-index-of-outer-loop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES.  This part of the documentation exactly answers my question!

> The special loop variable always points to the innermost loop. If it’s
>   desired to have access to an outer loop it’s possible to alias it:

```
<table>
{% for row in table %}
  <tr>
  {% set rowloop = loop %}
  {% for cell in row %}
    <td id="cell-{{ rowloop.index }}-{{ loop.index }}">{{ cell }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop