# Access list data with index in jinja template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I am getting this error when I use  any number with this also I have seen some solution on this site but I'm not able to solve or I am doing it in wrong way.
A Help will be appreciated. THANKS

sample data of resend_lst: ['0', '1', '0', '0']

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'resend_lst[0]'

```
{% for attendee_data in attendees_data %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.mobile }}</td>
            <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee_response.date }}</td>
          </tr>
         **resend_lst is a list data type and I need to access this with its index in that loop **
         {% if resend_lst[{{forloop.counter}}] == '0' %}
              <style>
                #response-{{forloop.counter}}{
                  display:none;
                }
                #cancel-{{forloop.counter}}{
                  display:none;
                }
                #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
                  display:none;
                }
                #ajax-loader{
                  text-align: center;
                  width:19px;
                  height:19px;
                }
              </style>
              {% else %}
              <style>

                #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
                  display:none;
                }
                #ajax-loader{
                  text-align: center;
                  width:19px;
                  height:19px;
                }
              </style>
              {% endif %}

        <-- some task -->
         {% endfor %}
```

Comment: if jinja2 in django, can you share your settings to make sure it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to build a new list to include both `attendees_data` and `resend_lst` at your Python back-end, however if you are still want to do in `Jinja` templates, you can achieve it through **nested looping** which is not good for performance.

### Django solution

**python part**

```
for i in range(len(attendees_data)):
    attendees_data['style_way'] =  resend_data[i]
```

**template part**

```
{% for attendee_data in attendees_data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.mobile }}</td>
          <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee_response.date }}</td>
        </tr>
        **resend_lst is a list data type and I need to access this with its index in that loop      **
          {% if attendee_data.style_way == 0 %}
            <style>
              #response-{{forloop.counter}}{
                display:none;
              }
              #cancel-{{forloop.counter}}{
                display:none;
              }
              #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
                display:none;
              }
              #ajax-loader{
                text-align: center;
                width:19px;
                height:19px;
              }
            </style>
          {% else %}
            <style>

              #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
                display:none;
              }
              #ajax-loader{
                text-align: center;
                width:19px;
                height:19px;
              }
            </style>
          {% endif %}
      <-- some task -->
    {% endfor %}
```

### old solution (work in Jinja2 template)

using loop.count as index for elements in the list and a for loop.

```
{% for attendee_data in attendees_data %}
  {% set outer_loop = loop %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee.mobile }}</td>
      <td>{{ attendee_data.attendee_response.date }}</td>
    </tr>
    **resend_lst is a list data type and I need to access this with its index in that loop      **
    {% for resend_data in resend_lst %}
      {% if loop.count == outer_loop.count and resend_data == 0 %}
        <style>
          #response-{{forloop.counter}}{
            display:none;
          }
          #cancel-{{forloop.counter}}{
            display:none;
          }
          #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
            display:none;
          }
          #ajax-loader{
            text-align: center;
            width:19px;
            height:19px;
          }
        </style>
      {% else %}
        <style>

          #loader-next-{{forloop.counter}}{
            display:none;
          }
          #ajax-loader{
            text-align: center;
            width:19px;
            height:19px;
          }
        </style>
      {% endif %}
  <-- some task -->
{% endfor %}
```

### Refs

- [Get loop index of outer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567291/get-loop-index-of-outer-loop)

Comment: attendee and resend_lst have their own dependencies so I can't

Comment: I am trying your Nested loop and it's giving me error     django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 610: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

and I have also use 'with' instead of 'set'

Comment: one more question, do you user `django template` or `jinja2 template`? because by default, django does not use `jinja2`. the code sample is for jinja2

Comment: by the way, can you paste the data sample for `attendee` and `resend_data`?

Comment: i'm using django template

Comment: after removing {% set outer_loop = loop %} and loop.count == outer_loop.count my code is working great but i don't know why  and I'm using innerloop Can you help me out... Why it is working

Comment: the reason is `{% set outer_loop = loop %} ` work only for `jinja`, but you are using django template, so removing it fix the error. `.count` work in django template too, but `outer_loop.count ` is not defined, in django template, use `forloop.counter` instead.

Comment: I don't think it should work that well, but if you paste the sample data of `resend_data`, it can help to identify the issue.